# Support of measure with CUE-characteristic polynomial density

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices

Let $Z_{N}(z):=\det(I-U_{N}z)$ on $\mathbb{T}$ for $U_{N}$ a matrix from the circular unitary ensemble. Then Webb showed that for $\alpha\in (-1/2,\sqrt{2})$

$$\lim_{N\to \infty}d\mu_{N}:=\lim_{N\to \infty}\frac{|Z_{N}(e^{i\theta})|^{\alpha}}{\mathbb{E}[|Z_{N}(e^{i\theta})|^{\alpha}]}d\theta= d\mu,$$

where $\mu$ is a singular measure called GMC ([Gaussian multiplicative chaos](http://Gaussian%20multiplicative%20chaos%20and%20applications)). The support of $\mu$ are called the gamma thick points.

> Q: Can we say anything about the support of $\mu$ from an eigenvalue point of view?

**Attempts**

Analogously to the thick points we study the set

$$\left\{\theta\in \mathbb{T}: \ln\left(|Z_{N}\left(e^{i\theta}\right)|^{\alpha}\right)< \gamma \ln\left(\mathbb{E}\left[\left|Z_{N}\left(e^{i\theta}\right)\right|^{\alpha}\right]\right)\right\}.$$

The places that $\ln\left(|Z_{N}(e^{i\theta})|^{\alpha}\right)$ blows up are on the eigenvalues of $U_{N}$. So in the $U_{\infty}$ case, if the same estimates work, we at least get that the gaps between the eigenvalues will be in the support of $\mu$.